# How to dynamically change (add) the active state class to a navigation link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to create a portfolio website. In order to not have to recreate the header for each page, I decided do add it using the PHP `include` function. My only problem now is when I click a link to navigate to another page the ***active*** link isn't changing respectively. 
**The included HTML**

```
<ul id="main-menu">
     <li><a href="index.php" class="active">home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.php">about us</a></li>
     <li><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var $menu = $("ul#main-menu li a");                
    $menu.click(function(){
        $menu.each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
        $(this).addClass("active");                  
    });
 });
```

I know that the problem is that each time the page loads - it resets the class ***active*** to the first link. What I don't know is: how to dynamically add the ***active*** class to the page-matching link?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
        var currentPHP = document.location.href.substr(i+1);
        $("ul#main-menu li a").removeClass('active');
        $("ul#main-menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']").addClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a function that runs on page load which selects the hyperlink with the same `href` as the page.

Alternatively, load the main content of the page through AJAX as opposed to the traditional page location change. JQuery has a good AJAX implementation. Search online for `jquery ajax`.

Another alternative would be to create a cookie onclick of the hyperlink, and set the selected one by reading the cookie. Although this would be very unreliable (back button, manual url entry, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLE:**

```
var link = document.location.href.split('/').slice(-1);   // retrieve page name
$('#main-menu li a.active').removeClass('active');        // remove class 'active'
$('#main-menu li a[href$="'+link+'"]').addClass('active');// and add it to a matching link
```

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/aguver/1/edit)*

Comment: @surajmishra yes it works. jsbin had some changes lately, you just had to change the version number (64) back to 1 http://jsbin.com/aguver/1/edit